# Android navigation drawer locking the swipe in fragment not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

Hi am facing a strange issue. I am trying to lock the swipe of navigation drawer in a fragment like below

```
 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        MainActivity.mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
    }
```

The above code working fine when the fragment loads.
But when in that fragment am opening the keyboard and entering some text in edittext and closing the keyboard the swipe is auto enable, which should not happen. Not sure why the keyboard open and close is enabling the navigation drawer swipe.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

Comment: are you using fragment  and  you need to find drawer again in it.

Comment: i want to lock the drawer in my fragment.   find a drawer in it?

Comment: you mean i have to put navigation drawer in fragment layout  and find it , can't i use activity drawer?

Comment: no, no need to put navigation drawer in fragment only need to find activity drawer in fragment.

Comment: we are doing this right?      DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167550/discussion-between-siddharth-patel-and-hari86).